They may well regret the decision in years to come

They may well regret the decision in years to come.

'may well' could be replaced with 'may very well' in the sentence above?
I see a lot 'may well' but don't see 'may very well'

Yeah, and "big" can be replaced with "very big",  or "quickly" can be replaced by "very quickly".  Of course, adding "very" changes the meaning by making it "stronger".

@JamesK I wondered if it's a 'fossil': 'may well+verb'

@gomadeng As far as I know, it is not. The word "very" is clearly not necessary, but there's nothing grammatically incorrect about its presence.

"very" indicates that the speaker believes the prediction is quite likely to come true.  "You may very well live to regret that decision."
